# I have a background image and over that image I have to put 3 x 3 images but images are overlapping

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a site in which I use bootstrap 4. I have a background image and over that image I have to put 3 x 3 images but images are overlapping. Also it's responsive.

Here is code:

```
        <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4" >
            <div class="column">
            <img src="assets/images/bg.png" class="img-responsive" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 " >
            <div class="column">
            <img src="assets/images/bg.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4" >
            <div class="column">
            <img src="assets/images/bg.png" class="img-responsive" >
            </div>

        </div>  
    </div>
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db3Pv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `background-image` of the div please have a look at this [jfFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwhpoq6u/)

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
  background-size: cover;
}

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.background1 {
  background-image: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.background2 {
  background-image: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-low-poly-design-background_1048-8196.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.background3 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPgx2MsZXRF0vNZ2_UX9VPouShDW33Ug4LBLzoAi_bPuqZdH0j);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col background1">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col background2">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col background3">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer look at above image i added i want background img then 3 x 3 images 3 in row and columns

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for a simple example of a fullscreen background image. You can edit the min-height value to get the effect you want.

Example: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/REzMZW

HTML:

```
<div class="full-home" style="background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800');" ></div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-home {
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-position:50% 50%\9 !important;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

With your code (I changed your image urls because I do not have access to yours):

```
<div class="full-home" style="background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800');"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```